# Define class in coffeescript, 'Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined'

Tags: javascript, class, coffeescript

I've encountered a 'Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined' error when trying to define a class using CoffeeScript.
As I'm new to both coffeeScript and JavaScript, I can't understand this error. Could somebody please help me.

Here is my coffeeScript code:

```
class Test
    constructor: (@data) ->
        @sums = @calculateSum()
        console.log @sums

    calculateSum: () =>
        sums = 0
        for i in [1...@data.length] by 1
            sums += @data[i]
        return sums

window.Test = Test
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your code is fine, seems that the source of error is somewhere else.

Comment: Btw, please note that you are indexing `@data` array starting from `1`, so you are missing `@data[0]` in the `sums`.

Comment: `@sums = eval(@data.join('+'))` would do very same as your `@sums = @calculateSum()` method. Btw, watch out for `eval` as this is risky to use it, but sometimes it gets quite handy.

Comment: Explanation of the `eval(@data.join('+'))`: this code would join all elentents of the array into a string while putting a '+' between them. Then we evaluate that string (run it as it would be a line in a JS file) to get result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are exporting is the function or in object oriented terms the class

To create an actual instance of the class you new too call it with the new operator.

new Test [100,100] and running this code does the right thing for me

Also though you might want to count from 0 and up and not from 1 and up unless you are purposely skipping the first element in the array.

Comment: I was wrong in my html code, add 'new' before 'Test' works, thanks for your reply and explanation.